Frozen cursor after boot Ubuntu 24.04 [Dell G15 Ryzen Edition]
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04, and when I turn it on the cursor freezes. I can open the terminal, so I guess everything else works. I tried booting with different kernel versions, and it worked just for the first boot, but later it froze too. I also tried doing something with psmouse in terminal, but I'm new to Linux so I don't understand it much.
On Windows 11 it works fine. I also plugged in a mouse on Ubuntu, and it also works. When I enter Settings I don't see any options for the touchpad, and when I unplug the mouse the touchpad still doesn't work

Unfortunately, I’m not home now and I don’t have the usb, i have GRUB dual boot

Is the mouse cursor working OK in the other OS of the dual boot?

Yes, on Win11 it works fine. I also plugged in a mouse on Ubuntu and it also works. When I enter settings I don’t see any options for the touchpad and when I plug off the mouse the touchpad still doesn’t work

Can you [edit] the question to include the model of the laptop or touchpad, as the issue could be related to the Ubuntu drivers for the touchpad.

I booted on the oldest kernel available in my GRUB and suddenly touchpad works, however I have to select the kernel every time I boot, cause the newest is picked as default. How can I change it?
